# How to get printer information using command line on Windows machine?

Tags: windows-xp

I need to get Windows XP printer information like printer port and driver name using command line.

I tried using Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools that give you such information but it needs administrative privileges. In our production scenario too we cannot rely on some external toolkits to be deployed just to get the printer info.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Try MSDN: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775908(WS.10).aspx

Comment: This gives options for the print service not how to get the printer information

Answer (score 1):

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PrinterConfiguration")
For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objPrinter.Name
    Wscript.Echo "Driver Version: " & objPrinter.DriverVersion
Next
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find - good stuff.

Comment: This is really close to what I wanted. But I needed the driver name as well. Here you go: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_printer.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could use WMI via a VB script to actually get the information, and then print it to the console. Running your VB script in cscript.exe rather than wscript.exe would run it in a console window.

[The ScriptingGuy article explains it a bit](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/07/19/how-can-i-retrieve-information-about-the-printer-driver-used-by-a-printer.aspx), but there is plenty more info about WMI available

Comment: It was a very nice article! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply go to C:\Windows\System32 and then run:

```
cscript prnmngr.vbs
```

From the command line... seems to give you all of the info you need

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725868(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Could not find prnmngr.vbs on Windows XP! So trying the WMI SCript option, thanks for the help!

Comment: From question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311201/get-default-printer-name-from-command-line, I found location is now `C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US`.