# Get default printer name from command line?

Tags: windows, windows-7

Microsoft Windows XP comes with a VBS script to manage local and network printers from the command line:

To Get the default printer details from command line:

```
cscript C:\windows\system32\prnmngr.vbs -g
```

To Get the list of printers added to the system from Windows command line:

```
cscript C:\windows\system32\prnmngr.vbs -l
```

Is there any equivalent commands for Windows 7? I just need to get the default printer details and get the list of printers attached to the system.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Windows 7 these same scripts are found in

```
C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US
```

Answer (score 8):

List of all printers names and shows default one (You can get more details read documentation)

```
wmic printer get name,default
```

If you want output to file use:

```
wmic printer get name,default > D:\catalog\file.txt
```

**Availability**

*The wmic command is an external command that is available in the below Microsoft operating systems as wmic.exe.*

```
Windows XP professional
Windows 2003
Windows Vista
Windows 7
Windows 8
Windows 10
```

Comment: This worked for me in Windows 10: `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %A in ('wmic.exe printer WHERE default^=TRUE get name /VALUE') do set "default_printer=%~A"`

Comment: `wmic printer where default=true get name` lists only the default printer.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 10, the scripts are found in the same place as Windows 7.
Execute the following command to display the default printer.

```
cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -g
```

Note if there is no default printer, the script will return nothing

Answer (score 1):

i found mine in the sideXside folder...

C:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-p..inscripts.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_en-us_0e83b619ada3e7ed\

i ran the following:
cscript C:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-p..inscripts.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_en-us_0e83b619ada3e7ed\prnmngr.vbs -g

it worked.

Answer (score 1):

To list active printer components on Windows 8.1:

**c:>cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -l | findstr "Printer name"**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove printer in Windows 8.1:

```
cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -d -p "Printer name"
```

I had trouble with a printer not showing in devices/printers so unable to remove it, although it was there when I pressed file > print in firefox. It was also stopping me from using the printer name for the actual installation (it bugged me having to append _1 at the end of the default printer!"

Answer (score 0):

Using a batch file (no VBScript files):

```
@echo off

::Get printer CLSID
for /f %%a in ('reg query HKCU\Printers\Defaults') do (set regkey=%%a)
::Get printer name from the previous CLSID

for /f "tokens=3*" %%a in ('reg query %regkey%') do (set printername=%%a %%b)
echo Printer name is: %printername%
```

I wish that could help you