# Zebra-printer TTP 2030 does not work

Tags: c++, printing, ofstream, zebra-printers

I'm trying to print "Hello World" in a Zebra Printer TTP 2030.

```
std::ofstream of;

of.open("Zebra TTP 2030");
if (of.is_open())
{
  debug(std::string("open : ok"));

  of << ticket.generateCode(); // return std::string
                               // ^XA^FO50,50^ADN,10,10^FDHello World^FS^XZ
  of.flush();
  of.close();
}
else 
  debug(std::string("open : ko"));
```

In the console, "open : ok" is trace.

I'm on a Microsoft XP Pro (VM). I'm working on Visual Studio 2010. The printer is setup on the VM.

Does someone know why a ticket is not created?

Comment: Have you tried `of.open("PRN:");`?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe It does not work.
My Zebra Printer is connected on the USB port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to print stuff from the command line is with `print`.  [Print, TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731623.aspx)

So you can achieve what you are asking by invoking `print` from your application. E.g.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>

void print_to_file(string filename){
    std::ofstream printer(filename);
    printer<<"Hello";
}

//create file with contents to print
int main(){
    std::string filename("print_this.tmp");
    print_to_file(filename);
    std::string command("print \\d:\\\\ServerName\\PrinterName ");
    std::system(command + filename);
}
```

As noted by the TechNet article, you have a few options for the printer name.

Comment: I tried this in a terminal : "unable to initialize device \\USB001\\TTP2030"

Comment: USB001 is not your Computer name name. I would suppose you can find that in your printer settings. Or maybe running `net user`.

Comment: @Gura More here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311201/get-default-printer-name-from-command-line

Comment: That works. But I had to do a trick
My Zebra printer uses the USB001 port. So I had to :
Right click on the printer, Properties>Ports
  * check enable printer pooling.
  * select port LPT1.
Then, the following code `system("print /d:lpt1 test.tmp")` worked

Answer (score 2):

You've created a text file called "Zebra TTP 2030" and your text is in there.

C++ has no standard way of sending output to a printer - you'll have to consult the Microsoft help to see how it's done.